# protractor - launch chrome with to disable web security for cors

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, selenium, selenium-webdriver, protractor

So our application works in production with a CORS enabled.

I have a project that isn't CORS enabled locally. Is there a way to disable web security for protractor? Is there a way for me to add arguments to the selenium instance ?

We're looking for a configuration based solution. Our local development machines are pretty locked down on what we can install. So is this possible?

What i have tried is setting chrome options: https://github.com/angular/protractor/issues/175

But that appears to only be used for chrome extensions.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

There is also [`args`](https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/docs/browser-setup.md#adding-chrome-specific-options) inside `chromeOptions`, where you can provide the [`--disable-web-security`](http://peter.sh/experiments/chromium-command-line-switches/#disable-web-security) and [`--user-data-dir`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35432749/disable-web-security-in-chrome-48-and-49) arguments.

If you are running the tests locally, make sure to [supply a profile location](https://www.chromium.org/developers/creating-and-using-profiles) for the `--user-data-dir`, otherwise Chrome will use the default profile and load the page in the current browser session (running with all of your extensions and settings).

```
capabilities: {
  'browserName': 'chrome',
  'chromeOptions': {
    'args': ['--disable-web-security', '--user-data-dir=~/.e2e-chrome-profile']
  }
},
```

Comment: Does this Works with POST request?

Answer (score 2):

@alecxe's solution wasn't working for me. I eventually came up with the following after some cli trial and error; I'm sharing my solution here (it took some hair pulling to figure it out) in case there are other lost souls out there having the same problem:

```
capabilities: {
    browserName: 'chrome',
    chromeOptions: {
        args: ['--disable-web-security', '--user-data-dir']
    }
}
```

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Worked for me:

```
chromeOptions: {
      args: ['--disable-web-security','--ignore-certificate-errors']
```

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30420113)